# What is the alternative of Response.Redirect (ASP.NET) in the typescript Success Callback method.?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, typescript

I have a scenario where I am making a call from one of the typescript method to a CS file which is  preparing a request url (encoded base64) , suppose I am returning the url back to my callback method  ,now in callback only I want to hit that url once I got the request URL, ,how to achieve that .

Comment: Show me the code what you have done up to now? and let us know what are you trying to do?

Comment: @BinaraThambugala Hi Binara , sorry I don't have the code ,its not mine,  but I explained the scenario ,the scenario is I have a typescript method which is calling a CS file method ,the CS file method return type I cant change (its plugin kind overridden method -Boolean)  ,the URL i am framing is there in the same method  ,now from CS Method I wanted to do Response.Redirect(URL)   which I am not able to do as I have to return Boolean type value but I can get the URL back to my callback method ,Can I do redirect similar thing in typescript callback